# How to get a child's type dynamically in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface with a finite set of keys, each with a different enum

```
interface Fizz {
    foo: Enum1;
    bar: Enum2;
    baz: Enum3;
}
```

I want to be able to pull a single type off dynamically in a function.

```
const func = (key: keyof Fizz) => (buzz: ???) => {}
```

How can I define the type of `buzz` based on the value of `key`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a generic function, like:

```
const func = <T extends keyof Fizz>(key: T) => (buzz: Fizz[T]) => {}

func('baz')(variable); // Now, `variable` need to be Enum3

func('foo')(variable); // And, `variable` need to be Enum1
```